# Where to start in estimating the days until payment of an invoice?

Tags: distributions, modeling, model-selection, survival, goodness-of-fit

I am in the process of modeling the random variable X as the days from issuing an invoice until its payment.  This variable is dependent on the days of credit for the invoice, so there are distinct X's depending on the days of credit, let's call them X_c.  I'm starting with the most common, X_30, which should be centered around 30 with a very heavy tail and a very rapid ramp up of the density getting to 30.

A basic histogram looks like this:

[image]

I have lots of data to try and fit but would like to get some pointer into which distributions might model this better from a conceptual point of view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As this is an example of [time to event analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_to_event_analysis), the obvious starting point would be the [Weibull distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution).

Comment: What would be the structural difference between the Weibull and the Gamma distribution to tackle this modeling?

Comment: Depends what you mean by 'structural'. The Weibull distribution is certainly more common in time-to-event analysis. It has a simpler cumulative distribution function, and it's the only distribution that has both the proportional hazards and accelerated failure time properties.

Comment: From watching some of the plots of weibull and gamma, it seems that weibull has more mass as it gets to the peak of the pdf whereas the gamma has more mass as it departs from the peak of the pdf.  I was wondering if this structure has any explanation.

Comment: One difference is that the Wiebull has a subexponential tail (one type of heavy tail) when the shape parameter is less than 1, whereas the Gamma distribution has an exponential tail.